# Azure App default name is being index by google

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I can’t say that I have seen this before.

The Azure app name is the default name that you give it when build the Azure app service.
It’s also used to validate the custom domain ownership with your domain register
It’s applied to the DNS as a CNAME record for the www of the custom domain

**DNS Set-up**
Type CNAME Domain Name customdoamin.com.au canonical name defaultname.azurewebsites.net

Q. Has anyone seen the Azure default domain been index by google before?
And if so how you would out why this maybe the case?

Comment: It is not very clear to me what exactly is your question here.

Comment: Has anyone seen the Azure default domain been index by google before?

And if so how you would out why this maybe the case?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to follow the guidance documented below, most likely adding a URL rewrite rule in your web.config to do a permanent redirect (301). This is what I use on my site.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
             <rule name="Redirect requests to default azure websites domain" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)"/>  
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mysite\.azurewebsites\.net$"/>
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://blog.test.com/{R:0}"/>  
            </rule>  
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Comment: Yes, we end up doing so, but still reviewing why Google is indexing the cname.